# Number must be positive and less than 64

Tags: atmega, assembly, avr-gcc

Im working with an ATMEGA328P, making a bit of USART code.

I used asm linked with C, with no less than 7 building errors.

All those were same "Number must be positive and less than 64".

Yes, I have defined __SFR_OFFSET to 0 and _SFR_ASM_COMPAT to 1. I don't have problems while accessing the PORTs, but when I try this line

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET        0
#define _SFR_ASM_COMPAT     1

#include <avr/io.h>

#define PORT                PORTD
#define LSB                 0
#define XCK                 4

.macro Blank
CBI PORT, LSB
.endm

.macro Black
SBI PORT, LSB
.endm

.org 0x13

    //*Emulated DMA*
    //R18 <-- [Z], Z++
    //USART <-- R18
    //if Z=0, Z=1024

    ld r18, Z+
    out UDR0, r18
    cp ZH, r1
    cpc ZL, r1
    brne Normal
    ldi ZL, 0x00
    ldi ZH, 0x02

    Normal:

reti
```

Comment: UDR0 is an SFR, not an IO port.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: I believe out is not a good instruction to use on an SFR. Check the instruction set manual.

Comment: UDR0 points to a memory location.  Load your data into that memory location.

Answer (score 2):

Operands of some assembler function are very restrictive, e.g. op code related to source/target register is limited by 6 bits, i.e. max. value is 64. I suppose at least "out UDR0,r18" is not correct because UDR0 is beyond port range. Check lines where compiler complains and double check possible operands in datasheet AVR *Register/Instruction set summary* paragraph. Also extra datasheet for ATMEGA instruction set does exist.

Comment: Hey... I used STS and it doesnt give any error now... Dont know whether it worked or not.. But now I have a different problem... OUT used 1 clock cycle but STS uses 2...

Comment: Yes, that is reason of fast OUT instructions but limited to registers where is supposed to be needed (ports, ...). UDR is not needed to be fast because UART is slower than CPU (and you need also wait if transmit register is empty).